# How to add concatenate button value into an api

Tags: javascript, dom

So I'm making a holiday finder "app" and I want to have buttons where when someone clicks the name of their country it inputs the country's value into the api string.

What I did was loop over all the buttons and save the target value to a variable which I then concatenated into the api. The thing is when I look in the console at the api fetched, where the country code is supposed to be it says "undefined".

I'm a bit confused on why so if you find the solution please explain it.

```
  let countrySelect = document.getElementById('country-select');
  let holidayName = document.getElementById('holiday-name');
  let holidayDesc = document.getElementById('holiday-desc');
  let holidayDate = document.getElementById('holiday-date');
  let holidayType = document.getElementById('holiday-type');
  let info = document.querySelector('.cell');
  let buttonValue;

  // get button values
    const button = document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(
      button => button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        buttonValue = e.target.value;
        console.log(buttonValue)
      })
    );


// api url
  const api = `https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?&api_key=<api key>&country=${buttonValue}&year=2020`;


// When the button is clicked fetch results
countrySelect.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fetch(api)
  .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {

        var apiResponse = data.response;


          console.log(apiResponse);
      }, networkError => {
        alert(networkError)
      })
  })
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry i'm a bit confused on your response. I want to to get the value of the button clicked (which contains the country value) and then add it to my api key so it can return the holiday based on the country. How does logging the whole object help? I'm just a bit confused. Sory.

Comment: @Nick can you give an example of the rendered `HTML` or could you check that the `button` elements actually have a `value` attribute set. If the `button` elements do not have a `value` attribute it will return `undefined`

Comment: @NewToJS Sure here are the buttons:                                                                       
      `<button type="button" value="ca">Canada</button>
        <button type="button" value="us">USA</button>
        <button type="button" value="mx">Mexico</button>`

Comment: @CertainPerformance No. When I console log buttonValue and click on a button it returns the value. Although when I add it to my api key it says undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define / redefine your `api` variable within the `countrySelect` event listener.

At the moment it is being defined before any buttons are clicked, so `buttonValue` is undefined. So even if your `buttonValue` changes in response to buttons being clicked, the `api` variable stays how it was, ie. with `country=undefined`.

```js
let countrySelect = document.getElementById('country-select');
let buttonValue;
 
const button = document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(
    button => button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      buttonValue = e.target.value;
      console.log(buttonValue);
    })
  );

// When the button is clicked fetch results
countrySelect.addEventListener('click', function() {
 const api = `https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?&api_key=<api key>&country=${buttonValue}&year=2020`;
 
 console.log(api);
});
```

```css
#country-select {
  border: 1px solid green;
  color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button value='uk'>
  UK
</button>

<button value ='us'>
  US
</button>

<div id='country-select'>
  Select Country
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping solve my problem. You were right about how the api was defined before the button click. Thank you.